# R Shiny Download Handler Check if File Exists

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using Shiny's download handler with a GET using httr package, which sends an XLSX file.  The code i have below works, but the question i have is there a way to check if that file any exists/return from the GET prior to sending a generated file out?  Right now, if the file doesn't exist, the code still creates a blank file (which I'd like to avoid).

```
  download_link_file <- reactive({
    url <-  paste0(EXPORT_DOWNLOAD_URL, '-', values$SOME_ID)
    url
  })

  output$downloadDataLink <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("file-export", "-", Sys.Date(), ".xlsx", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      GET(download_link_file(), write_disk(file))
    },
      contentType = "excel"
  )
```

Comment: You may create a condition with `exists` i.e. `if(exists(download_link_file()))`

Comment: You want to use `file.exists`, `exists` works on variables not files. However, even if you prevent the download with if, you will still see a failed download link file (at least in my chrome). Currently shiny has no exception handling in downloading. Read [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2611)